# Validate Transaction with serialization lib from a Tx Hash

Tags: transaction, cbor, hash

I want to validate Transactions to make sure they are actual Cardano txs with correct length, format etc.

I see that Transaction object in emurgo serialization library has an 'is_valid()' method that I guess returns if tx is valid or not.

The point is that I have the txHash (random example: 5ea96bdc7ab5e13c68838482eedf7b97382310f450bade5589bf500fed894ed7).

I am trying to convert from the txHash to the Transaction object, but library returns an error:

"Deserialization failed in Transaction because: Invalid cbor: not the right type, expected `Array' byte received` Bytes'"

This is what i am trying:

```
var txBytes = Buffer.from(txHash, 'hex');

const tx = WASM.Transaction.from_bytes(
    txBytes
);

isValid = tx.is_valid();
```

Any idea how can i get Transaction object from a txHash?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to go from hash to the object that generated the hash. But you can de-serialize the byte representation of a transaction for using in the WASM methods on it,with this:

```
 const transactionObjet = WASM.Transaction.from_bytes(
Buffer.from(CBORHextransaction, "hex")
```

);

Comment: Yes. That is what I was trying. But... what you call 'transactionHexString' is the same as the Transaction Hash? I guess not. I am getting transaction hashes, so, do i need to convert the hash to a hexString to be able to use it with the code above? Does emurgo serlization library has any method to do that?

Comment: No it is not the txHash... it is the CBOR hex-encoded whole transaction, you can not get the objet that generated the hash from the hash at a theoretical level .Thats the key concept of crypto. You can read more about the subject here: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#Funci%C3%B3n_hash .